# how to drop multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, drop

How to drop multiple columns in pandas and python ?

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":                        [ 
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":          
             ["loc2","loc1-loc3","loc3","loc1","loc2-loc1","loc2","loc3-loc2","loc2","loc1"],
              "category": 
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })    

def remove_columns(dataset,cols):
    for col in cols:
        del dataset[col]
    return dataset

for col in df.columns:
    df=remove_columns(df,col)
df.head()
```

in the code above the task is done and the columns are droped.

But when
I tried this code on streamlit where the user select multiple columns that he want to remove from the dataframe.

But the problem is that the system just take the first element and not all the item in the list.

like if the user select **location** and **source number** the **col** variable will contains just **location** and display the below error:

```
KeyError: 'location'
Traceback:
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app.py", line 373, in <module>
    sidebars[y]=st.sidebar.multiselect('Filter '+y, df[y].unique(),key="1")
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
```

## Streamlit code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 

#function drop unwanted columns
def remove_columns(dataset,cols):
    for col in cols:
        del dataset[col]
    return dataset

df =pd.DataFrame({
          "source_number":                        [ 
           [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
           "location":          
           ["loc2","loc1-loc3","loc3","loc1","loc2-loc1","loc2","loc3-loc2","loc2","loc1"],
           "category": 
           ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
           })    

drop_button = st.sidebar.button("Remove")
columns = st.sidebar.multiselect("Select  column/s", df.columns)
sidebars = {}
for y in columns:
    ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())   
    st.write(y)
    if (drop_button):
        df_drop=df.drop(y,axis=1,inplace=True)
        print(y)
    st.table(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
def remove_columns(dataset,cols):
    return dataset.drop(cols, axis=1)
```

And for call pass function with no loop - is possible pass scalar or list:

```
df = remove_columns(df,'location')

df = remove_columns(df,['location','category'])
```

EDIT:

If need remove column seelcted in multiselect use:

```
drop_button = st.sidebar.button("Remove")

#in columns variable are selected values
columns = st.sidebar.multiselect("Select  column/s", df.columns)
print (columns)

#so if use button remove values by variable columns
if (drop_button):
    df.drop(columns,axis=1,inplace=True)

    st.table(df)
```

Comment: i tried your first answer before you edit it i still returning the first item only.

and for the edit answer i need to call this function inside a for loop after the user select the required columns **Y** as **y** is the list of  selected columns

Comment: @user5980666 - So need remove `inplace` like `df_drop=df.drop(y,axis=1)` ?

Comment: @user5980666 - Or remove assign like `df.drop(y,axis=1,inplace=True)` ?

Comment: i tried removing the  assign but now when the user select the required columns  the **Y** includes the selected columns ...WHEN the user click on **remove button** it display only the first item and remove only the first item. AND display **the above error**

Comment: @user5980666 - Yes, because removed in loop. It means for each column `for y in columns:` is write `y` and if `drop_button` then in loop is removed column.

Comment: yes I know that because of the for loop but how can i get the selected columns in the list and pass it to the function without using the iteration  to go through all the selected columns ?

Comment: I think outside loop `if (drop_button):
        df.drop(y,axis=1,inplace=True)` should working

Comment: how is that ? isn't the Y variable initialized  inside the loop? the system will not recognize **Y** right ???

Comment: @user5980666 - agree. So not understand logic - you need write column by `write(st)` and then remove ?

Comment: the logic is that first the system display the dataframe as a table then the user is allowing to select the columns that he want to remove it  so that is why i need a for loop in order to display the **df.columns** in a variable then create a list that will contains the selected item from  **selected_column==df.columns**  in a new list... where the iteration is done on the **selected_column list** ... is there a better idea or logic to achieve this ??   **st.write(y)** is just to display the selected columns is as **print(y)**

Comment: @user5980666 - I try test and seems no loop necessary, added `EDIT` for soluion.

Comment: i tried your answer it works but still display this error:
`KeyError: 'category'
Traceback:
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app.py", line 354, in <module>
    ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err`

Comment: but how is this working i do not need to iterate over the list n order to go through all the items ?? i did not understand how it works

Comment: @user5980666 - I try add some comments - but I think it working with variable `columns` - There is selected values from multiselect and if press button need pass all seelcted values by variable `columns`. So for me working well

Comment: thanks for your help it  remove the selected columns but still display the error at this line  `ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())`

Comment: i did not understand you last comment

Comment: @user5980666 - No idea how combine it.

Comment: anw thank you for your help its always pleasure to learn from you

Answer (score 1):

Pandas have already implemented this inside of the function drop.
You can use pandas.drop with parameter columns = [columns that you want to drop] like this instead:

```
df.drop(columns = ["source_number","location"])
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: but i need to iterate over the list in order to includes these columns name when the user select them from the dropdown list as  i mentioned in my question